# "Did he say goodbye before he left?" OR "Does he say goodbye before he left?"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, sentence-choice

Which one is correct in this case:

> Did he say goodbye before he left?

OR

> Does he say goodbye before he left?

I think "**Did he say goodbye before he left?**" is correct but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Does he say goodbye before he left" is wrong as it contains a mixture of tenses, but the *meaning in context* tag may be significant - the correct version will depend when the question is asked in relation to when "he" left. For example :

"John just left." (past)

> "Did he say goodbye before he left?"

"John is leaving soon." (future)

> "Does he say goodbye before he leaves?"

"Will he say goodbye before he leaves?" would also be correct and arguably better, but the implication would be *for this occasion only*.

"Does he say goodbye before he leaves?" suggests that John has a policy of always saying goodbye before leaving.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
Have a good wk.